# cannot upgrade libgcc-s1 or libstdc++6... why?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 22.04, held-packages

Despite my best efforts, two packages remain on my (jammy) system that refuse to be upgraded:

```
enie...:~$ sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
libgcc-s1/jammy 13.1.0-2ubuntu2~22.04 amd64 [upgradable from: 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04]
libstdc++6/jammy 13.1.0-2ubuntu2~22.04 amd64 [upgradable from: 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04]
```

I've asked aptitude what it knows about the situation:

```
enie...:~$ sudo aptitude why-not libgcc-s1
i   libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 Depends libc6:i386 (>= 2.4)                 
i A libc6:i386                  Depends libgcc-s1:i386                      
i A libgcc-s1:i386              Breaks  libgcc-s1 (!= 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04)
```

... and

```
enie...:~$ sudo aptitude why-not libstdc++6
i   libxml2:i386    Depends libicu70:i386 (>= 70.1-1~)           
i A libicu70:i386   Depends libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2)             
i A libstdc++6:i386 Breaks  libstdc++6 (!= 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04)
```

I don't know enough to say why these packages are being held back. Anybody know?

This is preventing me from install gcc-13, which is making me :'-(

Comment: Guilty as charged. It's from:

`https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu jammy main`

That's a problem, is it? I like a LTS, but I'm a developer who needs more toolchain options than I get out of the box. What is the recommended way to do that?

Comment: @user535733 did you mean 23.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proximate (immediate) cause of your problem is the use of too many non-Ubuntu sources. Your non-Ubuntu-source A is providing packages that are incompatible with packages from non-Ubuntu-source B.

The underlying cause of your problem, the reason you need so many non-Ubuntu-sources, is that you are using the wrong release of Ubuntu for your needs. You have created a [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian) by bolting newer non-Ubuntu software onto an older LTS release. You are now learning that your monstrous creation is too afraid of fire to obey your commands.

LTS releases are simply not designed to be constantly updated to newer application versions and dependencies. LTS releases are intended for enterprise users that want consistent workflow (minimum changes) over the full five years.

Instead, try Ubuntu 23.04 or other 6-month release of Ubuntu. These releases DO snapshot new, updated versions and dependencies. They provide you stable six-month platform, then the whole platform updates again with the next 6-month release.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that since Ubuntu's docs specifically say to use these PPAs to get newer binutils and gcc packages for stable releases (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain#Toolchain_Updates), that it would not lead to a FrankenDebian. Was I wrong? What do the docs mean by, "The binutils and GCC packages are rarely updated in stable release updates. Newer versions of the toolchain packages can be found in PPAs instead." ?

Comment: Those are intended for rather more limited use than you have put them to. Analogy: I have a small model racing car that can leap across a half-meter gap. It cannot leap a three-meter gap. That's too far. Every six months adds another half-meter to *your* gap.